# stuck with switch in c project

Tags: c, switch-statement

i was trying to write a project in C
but it is not working

can someone tell me why? and what do i need to change?
i am trying to recive the day in week the birthday of a man will be next year
after he tell me the date in this year( example 14/11 day 2(monday)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int day,month,day_in_week;

void main()
{
    printf("Enter the date of your birthday in 2015 (day,month, day in week):\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&day,&month,&day_in_week);

   if(day_in_week<1 || day_in_week>7)
   {
       printf("Error date entered");
       return;
   }
   if(month<1 || month>12)
   {
       printf("Error date entered");
       return;
   }
   switch(month)
   {
   case 2:
       if(day<1 || day>28)
              {
                  printf("Error date entered");
                  return;
              }
   case 1: case 3:case 5:case 7:case 8:case 10:case 12:
       if(day<1 || day>31)
              {
                  printf("Error date entered");
                  return;
              }
   case 4:case 6:case 9:case 11:
       if(day<1 || day>30)
              {
                  printf("Error date entered");
                  return;
              }
   }

   switch(month)
   {
   case 1:case 2:
           day_in_week++;
           if (day_in_week>7)
               day_in_week= day_in_week-7;
   case 3:case 4:case 5:case 6:case 7:case 8:case 9:case 10:case 11:case 12:
              day_in_week=day_in_week+2;
           if (day_in_week>7)
               day_in_week= day_in_week-7;
   }

   switch(day_in_week)
   {
   case 1:
       printf("Sunday");
   case 2:
       printf("Monday");
   case 3:
       printf("Tuesday");
   case 4:
       printf("Wednesday");
   case 5:
       printf("Thursday");
   case 6:
       printf("Friday");
   case 7:
       printf("Saturday");
   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `break`s?

Comment: Yeah, you need to put `break;` after each piece of code in `case`. Eg.: `case 7: puts("Saturday"); break;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `break`:

```
switch(month)
   {
   case 1:case 2:
           day_in_week++;
           if (day_in_week>7)
               day_in_week= day_in_week-7;
           break;
   case 3:case 4:case 5:case 6:case 7:case 8:case 9:case 10:case 11:case 12:
              day_in_week=day_in_week+2;
           if (day_in_week>7)
               day_in_week= day_in_week-7;
           break;
   }
```

Also you should do it in next `switch` too.

 So, your code should looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int day,month,day_in_week;

void main()
{
    printf("Enter the date of your birthday in 2015 (day,month, day in week):\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&day,&month,&day_in_week);

   if(day_in_week<1 || day_in_week>7)
   {
       printf("Error date entered");
       return;
   }
   if(month<1 || month>12)
   {
       printf("Error date entered");
       return;
   }
   switch(month)
   {
   case 2:
       if(day<1 || day>28)
              {
                  printf("Error date entered");
                  return;
              }
   case 1: case 3:case 5:case 7:case 8:case 10:case 12:
       if(day<1 || day>31)
              {
                  printf("Error date entered");
                  return;
              }
   case 4:case 6:case 9:case 11:
       if(day<1 || day>30)
              {
                  printf("Error date entered");
                  return;
              }
   }

   switch(month)
   {
   case 1:case 2:
           day_in_week++;
           if (day_in_week>7)
               day_in_week= day_in_week-7;
           break;
   case 3:case 4:case 5:case 6:case 7:case 8:case 9:case 10:case 11:case 12:
              day_in_week=day_in_week+2;
           if (day_in_week>7)
               day_in_week= day_in_week-7;
           break;
   }

   switch(day_in_week)
   {
   case 1:
       printf("Sunday");
       break;
   case 2:
       printf("Monday");
       break;
   case 3:
       printf("Tuesday");
       break;
   case 4:
       printf("Wednesday");
       break;
   case 5:
       printf("Thursday");
       break;
   case 6:
       printf("Friday");
       break;
   case 7:
       printf("Saturday");
       break;
   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Here's a small help for you, to get it more clearly:

> Switch case statements are a substitute for long if statements that
>   compare a variable to several "integral" values.
>   The value of the variable given into `switch` is compared to the value
>   following each of the cases, and when one value matches the value of
>   the variable, the computer continues executing the program from that
>   point.

```
switch ( <variable> ) {
case this-value:
  Code to execute if <variable> == this-value
  break;
case that-value:
  Code to execute if <variable> == that-value
  break;
...
default:
  Code to execute if <variable> does not equal the value following any of the cases
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and about the "return" yes it will get out from all void main() which is what i need..( if the man was enter wrong number in the input..the program will finish

Answer (score 2):

A c `switch` command will keep running from one case to the next unless there is a `break` command at the end of the case.

```
switch (x) {
case 1:
  printf ( "case 1\n" );
//no break command, if x == 1, it keeps going
case 2:
  printf ( "case 1 and 2!\n" );
  break; // break command, it doesn't keep going to 3

case 3:
  printf ( "case 3 only\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you do not have a `break` at the end of each `case`. Once you add `break` at the end of each one of your `case` ( at the very end ), that should fix it.